# Installing StormCrawler 2.0

Tags: java, apache-storm, stormcrawler

I want to install StormCrawler 2.0, but I am unable to locate the appropriate installation instructions. In particular, what versions of Apache Storm, Zookeeper, and Java is StormCrawler 2.0 compatible with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [POM file for 2.0](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/2.0/pom.xml) contains the information you are after.

- Java 8
- Apache Storm 2.1 (likely to be upgraded to 2.2 shortly)
- according to [Storm's documentation](https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.2.0/Setting-up-a-Storm-cluster.html) ZK 3.3.3

You could have a look at [Ansible Storm](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/ansible-storm) and see if you can get it to work with Storm 2 with a few changes?